# Jquery: slideToggle, then scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `slideToggle` to display a `div` when a navigation button is clicked. It's working, but the `div` that I'm displaying is pretty tall, so you don't actually see much of it once it loads. The `div` sits directly beneath the button you use to trigger `slideToggle`. I would like to find a way to `slideToggle` the `div`, and then have the window scroll to the nav button, automatically displaying the entire previously hidden `div`.

`<a href="#">` doesn't work as it tries to jump to the element before the `slideToggle` function has executed. Is there a way to have the window scroll to the element after `slideToggle` has completed?

You can see what I have so far [here](http://verybradthings.com/sh/contact.html).

Click on the `printables` button to see what I'm talking about.

I also created a jsFiddle of the basic functionality, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spyrojoe/vyAMN/1/).

Comment: Please post your code in the actual question. -1

Answer (score 3):

The two answers provided by Chad and Robert are both valid, however, I like to write it a bit differently.

Below is an example based on your jsFiddle. The JS is the part you need.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#button" ).on( "click", function() { //Click
   $( "#content" ).slideToggle( "slow", function(){
   if ($(this).is(":visible")) { //Check to see if element is visible then scroll to it
    $('html,body').animate({ //animate the scroll
     scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 25 // the - 25 is to stop the scroll 25px above the element
    }, "slow")
   }
  });
   return false; //This works similarly to event.preventDefault(); as it stops the default link behavior
 });
});
```

```css
/* This is for the example */
#button{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:130px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#content{
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1200px;
    width: 170px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML for example -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="button">Click to expand content</a>
    
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $(element).slideToggle(250, function(){
        window.location.hash = "#content";
    });
});
```

Should work.

Comment: fixed missing opening "("

Comment: Works when I don't use the preventDefault object. Can you explain why I need that?

Comment: the `event.preventDefault();` is there to stop the normal functionality of the anchor being clicked.it will work without it, however it will present the same issue of scrolling to the location prior to the slideToggle

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off of Robert's answer, you could clean it up a bit by not using hashes.

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $a = $(this);

    $(element).slideToggle(250, function(){
        $(window).scrollTop($a.offset().top);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works when I remove the preventDefault portion. I guess I don't understand how that object works or why I need it here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Take this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kEqVc/. I set the link of the anchor to 'http://www.google.com/'. PreventDefault() takes the anchor and stops the standard behavior of the element, aka the link. So in this particular case, it stops the link from linking to another page, and allows the script to execute instead.